# Email confirmation not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, reset-password, email-confirmation

So I'm creating this Web application using the framework Laravel.
Now on the password reset page, everything's working great. [The email is sent correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpi3W.jpg),

[image]
 and also [received as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWqYi.png) but when I click on the confirmation link it shows an Error.

Received :
[image: Received]

Error:

> It says: Object not found!
>   The requested URL could not be found on the server. If you entered the URL manually, please check the spelling and try again.
>   If you think this is a malfunction of the server, please inform the webmaster about this.
>   Error 404
>   localhost
>   Apache / 2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL / 1.0.2l PHP / 7.1.7

Comment: i think you are not sending the correct url in your  mail. send that url in mail where you written the mail verify code or logic. in mail the correct url is not found thats the reason showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you sent, you have not updated the **APP_URL** variable in your .env file with the correct dev URL you are using (http://multiauth2.dev). Just update that .env variable and try the reset process again and it will work.

The reset image shows the raw link at the bottom of the email as **http:://localhost**.

Comment: Thanks man I totally forgot to check the link if it was correct!